# Dedicated oauth2 libraries for Android

Tags: android, wordpress, oauth-2.0, oauth.io, wordpress-login

I am developing for WordPress on Android and I hope to access a users profile picture, name and authenticate the user to post comments on my app which is linked to my WordPress blog.

I am looking for easy-to-implement dedicated oauth2 libraries that enable me do this.

Please could you be kind enough to offer suggestions? Pros and cons will be appreciated too.

I know a few like [oauth.io](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-android), [auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native-mobile/android/java), and [that of Google](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2), but I haven't used them before. So, please a clearer picture of these libraries will also be appreciated. If you've used any of them what's your experience like?

Answer (score 0):

We have created a premium OAuth 2.0 server plugin: https://lana.codes/product/lana-passport/

You can try it with the demo, and there is also detailed documentation for it.

However, OAuth is primarily for authenticating the user and querying the user's data via the `/resource` endpoint. So your primary goal is easily achievable.

In order to use the OAuth `access_token` to access the WordPress system and, for example, write a comment, further development is required in WordPress because this is not an OAuth task. So, your second goal can also be achieved, it just requires unique development.

#### Personal experience

I personally use the OAuth plugin to be able to log in to my WordPress websites using the Single Sign On button, which uses my primary WordPress website for authentication. So I use OAuth for a Single Sign On solution between two WordPress websites.